# Add connectionstring to web.config if not already set

Tags: iis, web-config, connection-string

I'm looking for a way to add a connectionString to my web.config file only when a connectionString with that name does not already exist.

For example:

I have this set in my current web.config file

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myDB" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=myDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In the IIS settings on the production server I also added the connectionString for "myDB" so that I don't have the production connectionString in the sources.
[[Image of the IIS settings]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rumdK.png)

If I am now going to Deloy my WebApp to the IIS I get the message that there already is an entry with the name "myDB".

Is there a way to only use the connectionString from the web.config file when there is not already one set in the IIS server settings?

Comment: This is not possible. You can achieve something similar using a build configuration and a web.config transformation but there is no 'add if not exists' directive for web.config files.

Answer (score 2):

You could remove the connection string before adding it by using a `<remove>` tag. If the specified connection string in a `<remove>` tag doesn't exist then nothing happens so this should work whether or not the connection string has already been added.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="myDB" />
    <add name="myDB" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=myDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" />
</connectionStrings>
```